# Akka Logback -- Named Loggers

Tags: akka, slf4j, logback

I'm trying to get named loggers to work with Akka and Logback.

My logback.xml looks like this:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>%-5level [%logger{36}] - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="Gregs.Admin.I" level="INFO" />
    <logger name="Gregs.Admin.D" level="DEBUG" />
    <logger name="Gregs.Admin.E" level="ERROR" />

    <root level="debug">
            <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

...and my application.conf (relevant clip) looks like this:

```
akka {
    loglevel = "ERROR"
    stdout-loglevel = "ERROR"
    loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
}
```

I get the logs I expect but don't see my "Gregs.Admin.x" name anywhere in my format.  I get things like this:

```
ERROR [akka.remote.EndpointWriter] - AssociationError [akka.tcp://AWECluster@10.154.147.189:9010] -> [akka.tcp://AWECluster@10.154.147.189:9011]: Error [Association failed with [akka.tcp://AWECluster@10.154.147.189:9011]] [
akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with [akka.tcp://AWECluster@10.154.147.189:9011]
Caused by: akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$associate$1$$anon$2: Connection refused: /10.154.147.189:9011
]
```

So I'm getting "akka.remote.EndpointWriter" instead of the logger name I want.

This is important because my real application is multi-node distributed so I need some way to differentiate messages from different nodes in an aggregated log file and I was hoping to do this by setting different logger names on different nodes.

Comment: Have you read this section of the documentation? http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.1/scala/logging.html#SLF4J

Comment: I do see that behavior and using %X{akkaSource} I can parse out the Akka URI in the error message.  Fantastic for Akka logging (and my own), but it doesn't seem to help uncaught exceptions, which remain "naked" in the logs.  I was hoping to set the logger name in the logback.xml file and have it go through with the error messages so I could set the string to anything I want.